# Maximum values of Trigonometric graphs

Tags: trigonometry

When you have the function in the form of a fraction, eg. $y= \frac{a}{\sin x}$, would $\sin x$ have to be a minimum of $-1$ in every case to give a maximum value for $y$? If you have sinx as $-1$, $y=-a$ which is a lower value than when you have sinx as a maximum of $1 (y=a)$ so it doesn't work. I'm a bit confused. Please do enlighten me with the correct answers.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Note that for $a>0$  when $\sin x \to 0^+$ the function tends to $\infty$ and when $\sin x \to 0^-$ the function tends to $-\infty$ (see the plot for $\frac 1 {\sin x}$ [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%201%2Fsin%20x)).

What is true is that local minimum and local maximum are attained when $\sin =\pm 1$ indeed

$$f'(x)=\frac{2\cos x}{\cos (2x)-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $|\sin x|\le 1,$ it follows that whenever $\sin x\ne 0,$ we have that $$\frac{1}{|\sin x|}\ge 1.$$ Thus, if $a\ge 0$ and $\sin x$ doesn't vanish, then $$a\frac{1}{|\sin x|}\ge a,$$ and otherwise when $a$ is negative.

Comment: Please could you rephrase that?